# Selecting all rows on a column containing values

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called skills, which has 2 columns: developer_id and language_id.
I want to get all the developers that have a set of language_id's (the developer must have all to be returned).

I tried two approaches:

```
SELECT developer_id FROM skills WHERE language_id = 256
INTERSECT
SELECT developer_id FROM skills WHERE language_id = 85

HashSetOp Intersect  (cost=24192.94..422840.17 rows=114424 width=4)
  ->  Append  (cost=24192.94..413497.17 rows=3737200 width=4)
        ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 1"  (cost=24192.94..183000.11 rows=1292452 width=4)
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on skills  (cost=24192.94..170075.59 rows=1292452 width=4)
                    Recheck Cond: (language_id = 256)
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on skill_dev_lang_idx  (cost=0.00..23869.83 rows=1292452 width=0)
                          Index Cond: (language_id = 256)
        ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 2"  (cost=45763.23..230497.06 rows=2444748 width=4)
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on skills skills_1  (cost=45763.23..206049.58 rows=2444748 width=4)
                    Recheck Cond: (language_id = 85)
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on skill_dev_lang_idx  (cost=0.00..45152.05 rows=2444748 width=0)
                          Index Cond: (language_id = 85)
```

and

```
SELECT developer_id FROM skills
WHERE language_id IN (256,85)
group by developer_id
having count(*) = 2

HashAggregate  (cost=262124.17..266259.96 rows=330863 width=4)
  Group Key: developer_id
  Filter: (count(*) = 2)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on skills  (cost=66996.18..243438.17 rows=3737200 width=4)
        Recheck Cond: (language_id = ANY ('{256,85}'::integer[]))
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on skill_dev_lang_idx  (cost=0.00..66061.88 rows=3737200 width=0)
              Index Cond: (language_id = ANY ('{256,85}'::integer[]))
```

but both of these are slow (3-4 seconds).

I have an index on both the dev_id and language_id. There are ~30 million rows.

Comment: do you have single `unique index (language_id, dev_id)`? in this particular order

Comment: @Lashane yeah that exact index

Comment: can you post execution plan?

Comment: @Lashane added the plan for both

Comment: so, you're retrieving ~100k records per second? do you think it slow?

Comment: @Lashane I just realized that I forgot to include a LIMIT 100 at the end... That "unique index" you suggested was a big help though, before even with the LIMIT it ran slow.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `explain analyze` instead of the plain `analyze`

Answer (score 0):

Your query is counting grouping and counting ALL 3M records (filtered by an index scan from your total 30M+), and then filtering by count(*) = 2. Perhaps the following will perform better:

```
SELECT s.developer_id
FROM skills s
JOIN skills s2 ON (s2.developer_id = s.developer_id)
WHERE s.language_id = 256 AND s2.language_id = 85
```